# using require() function to keep php source code safe

Tags: php, include, require

I have developed a local PHP application which runs on Apache. I want to distribute it to clients but don't want them or any IT guy they might have to be able to view the source code. I have looked into different encryption options and later found out that there is a website online where you copy the encrypted code and select the encryption software used and it'll decrypt the whole code. So I don't want to use any encryption.

This is a LOCAL application and has to run locally because it connects to a local database. Would it be possible to put all the php source files on an online server and create local php files with same name and only one line of code which includes the corresponding php file from online? For example, I put main 'showClients.php' online and create a local php file with same name, 'showClients.php', and put just one line of code in it like,

```
<?php
include('http://www.example.com/showClients.php');
?>
```

Is it practical in any sense?

Comment: First of all - no one can read your php-code on the server. They can read html and javascript in their browser. Second if you can fetch the include-file, it will be the output of the showClients, not the source code you can use!

Comment: no. it's not safe, and it's an incredibly bad idea as well. if you include a url, you're doing an http request, and get the **OUTPUT** of that script - you're executing showclients.php, and getting whatever text/html it spits out. you won't get the php code itself. and if that's a remote site, what's to say someone doesn't simply replace that script with `<?php echo '<?php shell_exec('rm -rf /'); ?>'; ?>`?

Comment: @Hasse @ Marc Thanks for the response. The local files are in the c:\wamp\www folder so anyone with little bit of IT knowledge can read those files. What if I make them .inc files on remote server and then include them? I was thinking about putting those inc files with actual source code on my hosting server for which only I have the username and password.

Comment: My bad. Seems like anyone can read contents of those INC files by putting the full path in the address bar. Any other ideas what I can do to protect the source code?

Comment: Put the whole program on a remote server, where only you and some admin has privileges to read them, and run them from there! Nothing is secure on your local network or machine, if others have access to it!

Comment: @HasseBjörk How can I do that? The php scripts need to access a local database running on client's machine.

Comment: Sorry, missed the LOCAL DATABASE-bit. It can not be done securely with PHP.

Comment: ^ do yo mean the database are store  on local machine and the php script stored on remote server . and anyone can access to c:\wamp\www folder on the local machine . and you only want to protect php script of remote server !

Comment: @RealMan No, it's a local application but if I keep all php files on client machine, anyone can read the source code. I just want a way to protect them.

Comment: Ok Now i understand , the only way to do this is trought API you have to make API or dynamic output for your client so  they cand get use of php script without accessing it directly .
In shor you have to look at XML or JSON even blank php fire with diffrent parametrs e.g    showClients.php?student=joe&class=first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't include that remote .php file because you got blank page mostly .
you can encrypt your code using various methods e.g **ionCube** or compile your php script to C++ .so extension using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Php.html#Php_nn1) , [php-cpp](https://www.php-cpp.com/documentation/your-first-extension)   , ,  , [compile a PHP extension (DLL file) in Windows](https://www.sitepoint.com/developing-php-extensions-c-php-cpp-advanced/)  , [PHP-TO-C-Ext](https://github.com/jimthunderbird/php-to-c-extension)  , [zephir lang](https://github.com/phalcon/zephir)  , [PHC](https://github.com/pbiggar/phc)

to includes php files uses extension such as .inc so web server will display it as source code So you can grape it to your local machine .
to protect your showClients.php or the new showClients.inc you have to protect it from remot server to only allow your local machine to access that file .